# How do I disable the Guest user from shutting down the PC while the Admin is logged in?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, guest-account

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate. I found out how to disable the Guest user from shutting down at all, but then they can't shutdown even if Admin account is logged off.

Edit: To clarify a little, say I want to give my PC to someone, I usually click on Switch User and log in using the Guest account. That way, they can't access my account as it asks for a password. I want that in such a case, they shouldn't be able to shut down the PC as my admin account is still logged on.

However, if someone else boots up the PC themselves and uses the Guest account, then they should be able to shut it down too, as my Admin account hasn't been logged on.

Comment: Please add how to disable the Guest user from shutting down.

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-users-shutting-down-restarting-windows-computer

Comment: @Private - We don't need that information to answer this question.

Comment: @Cerberus - its not clear what your end goal is.  The title of the question indicates that an Administrator account is logged in, so it would be as simple as, switching the user to the Administrator account.

Comment: Logging into the Admin account will ask for the password, which a Guest wouldn't have.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited the post to clarify my end goal here.

Comment: Your end goal isn't feasible.  You can either give the power to the user to shutdown the machine or take it away.  The group policy that controls this permission is a Allow Deny type permission.

Comment: @Ramhound I asked to find how Cerberus did it...if it was a script, I thought I could make edits to it to solve the problem.

Comment: @Private I don't mind using scripts in order to achieve this, but I don't have the knowledge to write them myself

Comment: @Cerberus - He did it with the group policy.  Like I said how it was done specifically isn't really vital to the question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my question answered [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-i-disable-the-guest-user-from-shutting-down/432392c4-a399-4170-bed1-4d354a47007c?tm=1460625213044) -

> This is the correct method. It is also robust in that it is
>   unconditional. If you wish to have your cake and eat it then the Guest
>   account must use a powerful "agent" to perform the shutdown task. A
>   scheduled task would be such an agent. It could work like so:
>
> 1. Create a scheduled task that runs Script1 to perform these tasks:
> 2. Check if the file C:\Shutdown\Shutdown.txt exists.
> 3. If it does not, exit from the script.
> 4. If it does, delete Shutdown.txt.
> 5. Check if there is a live Administrator session. If yes, exit from the script.
> 6. If there is no live Administrator session, shut down the machine, using shutdown.exe.
> 7. The task must run once every 3 minutes under an admin account.
> 8. Create a desktop shortcut for the Guest user that invokes Script2 to perform these tasks:
> 9. Check if there is a live Administrator session.
> 10. If it does, create a pop-up to inform the user that the machine cannot be shut down.
> 11. If it does not, create the file C:\Shutdown\Shutdown.txt. The scheduled task will "see" this file and will shut down the machine.

Comment: Could you add the actual text. Assume that that link will die some day.